# Serialization between two applications

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2012, serialization, class-library

I have developed a Visual Basic.net application that uses serialization to save an object. I am wanting to open and save this object in two different Visual Basic.net applications.

What is the best way to do this? Do I need to create a class library to do this?

Can I please have some help for this?

**EDIT**

I am wanting to be able to open and save the object in both applications.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on how complicated your data is, you should be able to simply mark your data's class with a `<Serializable>` attribute. You can then simply call the `Serialize` method in one application, save to disk, then read the file into your other application and call `Deserialize`.

You will need to define the class in both applications, which is easiest to do by sharing a common library.

See the MDSN example for [basic serialization](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms973893.aspx#objserializ_topic4).

Comment: When trying to open the serialized object in the second application, I get the following error: Unable to find assembly 'TestSerializationSaveOpenObjectProject2, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null'.

Answer (score 0):

You can write/read to xml, then you would just have to check the folder where you save them from the other app to see if a new file has been created or updated.

**Function to serialize object and write to xml**

```
Public Function MyObjectFileGeneration()
    Try
        Dim strPath As String = System.IO.Path.GetDirectoryName(System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().CodeBase)

        strPath = Replace(strPath, "file:\", "")

        Dim myObj = Form1.MyObject



        Dim objStreamWriter As New StreamWriter(strPath & "\MyFolder\MyObj.xml", False)

        Dim x As New XmlSerializer(s.GetType)
        x.Serialize(objStreamWriter, MyObj)

        objStreamWriter.Close()

        Return True

    Catch ex As Exception
        'Do something here if failure...
        Return False

    End Try
End Function
```

**Function to read xml and de-serialize to object**

```
Public Function GetMyObjFromXMLFile() As MyObj

    'check if file exists first...

    If xmlFileExists() Then



        Dim strPath As String = System.IO.Path.GetDirectoryName(System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().CodeBase)



        Dim objStreamReader As New StreamReader(Replace(strPath & "\MyFolder\MyObj.xml", "file:\", ""))

        Dim MyObj As New MyObject
        Dim x As New XmlSerializer(MyObj.GetType)
        MyObj = x.Deserialize(objStreamReader)
        objStreamReader.Close()

        Return MyObj


    Else
        Return New MyObj

    End If


End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

I wish there was an easy way to do this, but unfortunately, I hit this wall also..

Serializable data can only be reread by the SAME application. (it gives you a lovely error message about this.) I tried using a serialized connection for simplified packet transfers, unsuccessfully..

Depending on how good you are at programming, I have a recommendation on this one..

Serialize your variables to a memorystream, then cut the header section out and shove it to another file stream, then when you reload it, save a variable to a memorystream to get the new header, then attach the remaining data, then read serialization..

haven't tried it yet, but when I get back to it, this is my next method.

I did see an XML method, but recommend using a compression/encryption library to keep your data safe.. did see some simple ways to possibly do that..

Sorry, I don't have code on this round, but when I investigate it, I will append this response..